# How can I update the data type of a column inside a table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, migration, database-migration

I am trying to update the data type of my column due to it requiring encryption. I created a new migration to do so and have tried this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn(['team', 'service_number']);
        $table->string('team', 188);
        $table->string('service_number', 188);
    });
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'team' (SQL: alter table `users` add `team` varchar(1024) not null, add `service_number` varchar(1024) not null)
```

How can I update the data type of my columns in my table?

Comment: Tru using two schemas, first to drop and second to create

Comment: This makes sense. Is there not a better way to do this or is this limited due to this not being a transaction? @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: what type are these fields currently that you want to alter?

Comment: integer @lagbox

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#modifying-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do this (though that won't drop the columns):

```
    $table->string('team', 188)->change();
    $table->string('service_number', 188)->change();
```